Google Colab Error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow_quantum'
I am recieveing the error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow_quantum' in google colab when i try importing tensorflow-quantum
I tried installing the package "tensorflow-quantum" over and over again. I also installed it manually by cloning it from github to no avail. Also note that i have read the instructions for installing the package including the python version requirement and followed them to no avail. I tried same process in jupyter-notebook but still get the same error message. Its so frustrating.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

You need to show some code to let us help you friend.

What is the code you are working from?

If my answer was helpful in solving your question can you please mark it as accepted. This will indicate future users who have similar issue that the particular answer was the solution.

I think google colab has been updated to use Python 3.11 as its default starting April 2024. You can check the python version by running
!python --version

tensorflow-quantum is only compatible with Python 3.7, 3.8, 3.9. So if you are using Python 3.11 (or python 3.10), attempting to do pip install tensorflow-quantum will result in error.
To fix this issue you can use python 3.9 in google colab
